# How do I implement the service locator pattern with generic base classes?

Tags: c#, generics

I have gotten myself into a catch 22 and cannot seem to find my way out. I'm trying to implement a simple [Service Locator][1], represented by the GetInstance-method in the example code below. Now the problem is I get a compiler error on the return statement saying:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'Cyberspace.SubClass' to 'Cyberspace.BaseClass<T>'`

I've tried rewriting so that the SubClass is a generic class itself, but then I get compiler error on the return statement in the DoSomething-method.

Can anyone make this code compile, retaining the Service Locator pattern principles which allow me to have an abstract return type in the GetInstace-method? Or am I trying to acheive something impossible here?

```
namespace Cyberspace
{
    class BaseClass<T>
    {
        BaseClass<T> GetInstance() 
        { 
            return new SubClass();
        }
        virtual T DoSomething() { return default(T); }          
    }

    class SubClass : BaseClass<OtherClass>
    {
        public override OtherClass DoSomething()
        { 
            var other = new OtherClass { Description = "Generics are hard"};
            return other;
        }
    }

    class OtherClass
    {
        internal string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
namespace Cyberspace
{
    class BaseClass<T>
    {
        static BaseClass<T> GetInstance() // The "Service Locator" method
        { 
            return new SubClass<T>(); 
        }
        internal virtual T DoSomething() { return default(T); }        
    }

    class SubClass<T> : BaseClass<T> where T: OtherClass
    {
        internal override T DoSomething()
        { 
            var other = new OtherClass { Description = "Generics are hard"};
            return (T) other;
        }
    }

    class OtherClass
    {
        internal string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This yields the following error on line `return new SubClass<T>();`

`The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Cyberspace.SubClass<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'Cyberspace.OtherClass'`

Comment: There are a few options. The easiest of which is to change `BaseClass<T> GetInstance()` to `BaseClass<OtherClass> GetInstance()`. The more complex ones involve having SubClass be generic and/or enforce constrains on what the generic type could be via the `where` clause. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: Changing to BaseClass<OtherClass> GetInstance() locks the method to only that particular class. I want a generic method. I've looked into making the subclass generic with where-constraints as well but this yields problems in the DoSomething method()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a type parameter `T` you declare: "I don't care what the type actually is. I just need *some* type, any type at all. Call it `T`.". But in your case it looks like you want a specific type. No need for generics, then.

```
class SubClass : BaseClass<OtherClass>
{
    internal override OtherClass DoSomething()
    { 
        var other = new OtherClass { Description = "Generics are hard"};
        return other;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the following work?

```
        var other = new OtherClass { Description = "Generics are hard"};
        return (T) other;
```

Because `T` might be derived from `OtherClass`. You cannot convert `OtherClass` to a class derived from `OtherClass`. Makes no sense and the compiler is smart enough to catch it.

---

The discussion in the comments lead to the following workaround:

```
return (BaseClass<T>)(object)new SubClass();
```

Of course, this only works, if the types line up at runtime.

Comment: It looks like I want a specific type because the example only instantiates it with "OtherClass". I will however be using other classes than OtherClass (pun intended) when instantiating in the real world application.

Comment: The point applies. Why do you need a type parameter T on SubClass?

Comment: Oh I see - I thought you meant for the BaseClass as well. No I don't need it for the subclass, but then the BaseClass will not compile - see the first code example.

Comment: Your GetInstance implementation doesn't really make sense because you promise to be able to provide any type T, but you only *can* provide a SubClass which is different. Not knowing your intentions fully, here is a workaround: `return (BaseClass<T>)(object)new SubClass();` Of course, this only works, if the types line up at runtime.

Comment: If you post that workaround as an answer (or embed it in the existing), I will mark that as the correct answer. It works - I'm happy! :-) As for my intentions, maybe they're more clear if you check this improved version I've posted at GitHub with better naming and explanation: https://gist.github.com/3012094#

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually didn't think there was any solution to this problem. Although I do realize this is not optimal (risk of cast exception runtime), it works and solves my problem rather elegantly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unclear on what you're really trying to do, but I can tell you why that compile error is happening.

Anything that is returned from this method:

`BaseClass<T> GetInstance()`

*Must* be able to handle any type `T` (because you have no type constraints). `SubClass` can only handle one type, not all types.  Therefore you can't return it.